# Custom "open in " action title for iOS app that opens a document type

Tags: ios, cocoa, cfbundledocumenttypes

I have an app that can open a custom document type (according to
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

When I tap on a file in another application, I get menu of apps that I can open the file in:

"open in Google Drive", 
"open in MyApp", 
"Mail"

I noticed that the Mail app doesn't have a "open in " prefix.

MyApp is designed to "upload" the file type. Is it possible to change the text so it reads "Upload via MyApp?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple uses private APIs for their own apps, and that's why they can display the Mail option differently.  For all other apps, it will always be "Open in MyApp", where MyApp is whatever you've set as your Bundle Display Name.